# How can I add padding to a SwiftUI View's context menu preview?

Tags: swiftui, contextmenu, lazyvgrid

I have a LazyVGrid with items in it, I don't have any padding on the items because I prefer to let the layout of the LazyVGrid manage the spacing between cells. but when I open the context menu on the item it displays the item as it is with no padding.

[image]

how can I tell the context menu to show the preview with added padding around the cell?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 16 and higher, the `contextMenu` modifier takes a preview argument that is of type `some View`.

This view could have padding, or a customised `Image`. To get padding to work, you might need to wrap the views and padding in a parent view at the top of the hierarchy.

You haven’t shared your code so I can’t give you an example in your context, but it could look like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Example")
            .contextMenu {
                // Context menu stuff
            } preview: {
                // Preview here
            }
    }
}
```